# volume mount tensorflow container for persistance storage

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tensorflow, containers

Hi I am trying to get `TensorFlow` notebook folder mounted to `/src/work` folder in Ubuntu.

```
sudo docker run -it -v /src/work:/HOME/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.3.0
```

I have tried many combination of -v flags. It is not reading the files already in my work folder or saving new files to it.

Comment: "TensorFlow notebook folder mounted to `/src/work`". This suggests you're trying to mount the notebook to the container. Is that correct?

Comment: @Shanky  according to the offical dockerfile
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile

WORKDIR "/notebooks"

Comment: The dockerfile helped. Please see my edited answer. Also consider editing your question to avoid confusion for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mounting the volume incorrectly, precisely the path. It should be

`-v ~/[absolute path from $HOME]/src/work:~/notebooks/`

**Explanation:**

Since your working directory is `/notebooks`, which places it at `/$HOME/notebooks`. You use `~` to get to the `$HOME`.

Comment: That worked.  

docker run -it -v /home/linuxnikola/work:/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:1.3.0

Sorry I was confused with /HOME/notebooks

Now the files are persistent but I am not loading the demo files from the container.  But that is not a big deal.

cheers.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: the latest tensorflow containers now serve from /tf so instead of `:/notebooks` place `:/tf`

Answer (score 1):

This will work as expected. Make sure you have a `src` folder in the host's root directory (`/`) eg. you may have `~/repo/src/work` this is different than `/src/work`. In the container, the files will show up exactly on root's `/HOME/notebooks` directory.

Make sure you are checking the files in the right directory.