# How can I making the host directory sharable on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tensorflow, nvidia-docker, sharefile

I can't see the Jupyter files in /home/easton/notebooks, how can I fix this?

```
nvidia-docker run -it --rm --name tf -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /home/easton/notebooks:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:1.14.0-gpu-py3-jupyter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mounting the wrong directory, according to documentation the correct path for `TensorFlow` is `~/notebooks/` or `/tf/notebooks` in the container.

Docker run command will be

```
nvidia-docker run -it --rm --name tf -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v /home/easton/notebooks:/tf/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter
```

You can check offical [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45810450/volume-mount-tensorflow-container-for-persistance-storage)

**Optional Features**

> jupyter tags include Jupyter and some TensorFlow tutorial notebooks.. They start a Jupyter notebook server on boot. Mount a    volume to
>   /tf/notebooks to work on your own notebooks.
>
> `docker run -it --rm -v $(realpath ~/notebooks):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3-jupyter`
>
> Run a Jupyter
>   notebook server with your own notebook directory (assumed here to be
>   ~/notebooks). To use it, navigate to localhost:8888 in your browser.